# i'm automating an angular registration form and i have a dropdown box whose id is span and how to select choice based on user input

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver

Here is my code:

```
WebElement id1=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".mat-select-placeholder"));
Select drid = new Select(id1);
drid.selectByIndex(1);
```

And i'm getting error element was select but it was span.

How to solve this?

HTML :

```
<mat-form-field id="select-shyam"> <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label> <mat-select id="select-parth"> <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods; let index = index" [value]="food.value" id="{{'select-parth-' + index}}"> {{food.viewValue}} </mat-option> </mat-select> </mat-form-field> <br> <br>
```

Error :

> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element
>   should have been "select" but was "mat-select" Build info: version:
>   '3.10.0', revision: '176b4a9', time: '2018-03-02T19:10:56.039Z' System
>   info: host: 'GTJPCPU07', ip: '192.168.40.160', os.name: 'Windows 10',
>   os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161' Driver
>   info: driver.version: unknown at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.(Select.java:47) at
>   EtaCore.Setup_Clear_Roles.addnewwrole(Setup_Clear_Roles.java:118) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace of error for better debugging.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "mat-select"
Build info: version: '3.10.0', revision: '176b4a9', time: '2018-03-02T19:10:56.039Z'
System info: host: 'GTJPCPU07', ip: '192.168.40.160', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.<init>(Select.java:47)
 at EtaCore.Setup_Clear_Roles.addnewwrole(Setup_Clear_Roles.java:118)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: here is my code and below the code, i'll add the element details  WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='select-role-0']"));
             
             myElement.click();
             
             Select select = new Select(myElement);
             
              List<WebElement> Checkbox = select.getOptions();
     
       for(WebElement e : Checkbox) {
         if(e.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Login")) {
             e.click();
         }

Comment: My element id is like <mat-select id="select-role-0"

Comment: If you see the error, you can see that the error message is self explanatory. You cannot use select methods on tags that are not Select.

Comment: Can you help me, how can i go through options of this kind of drop down and select one value from that

Comment: Hard to know how it can be solved without knowing the relavant HTML. Please post the HTML and how the options are showing on DOM.

Comment: <mat-form-field id="select-shyam">
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select id="select-parth">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods; let index = index" [value]="food.value" id="{{'select-parth-' + index}}">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<br>
<br>

Comment: above is the code, i use xpath with id and i want to go through the list of options and select choice based on user. but when use <list> it shows element has to be select but it is mat-select

Comment: Get the list of the elements and then put it in a list - if you know the exact position of the element, then use index in the list and then get the element.